# LINQ query to find out records between two given dates when dates are in String format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

The one I tried using was:

```
.Where(f => f.Date.CompareTo(Date1) >= 0 && f.Date.CompareTo(Date2) <= 0)
```

It gives correct results for the same year - If Date 1 - 1/20/2017 and Date 2 -1/30/2017

But  If Date 1 - 1/20/2015 and Date 2 - 1/30/2017

It returns results for all the years in between 1/20 and 1/30

Changing into `DateTime` is not possible and I am trying to achieve it using String when the Date format will be same always.

Comment: You cannot do `string` comparisons on dates unless they are in a format like yyyyMMDD.  You have to parse them either to `DateTime` or to the meaningful parts (month, day, and year) in order to do your comparison.

Comment: Storing dates as strings is a form of denormalization. In other words, it's *bad database design and should be avoided*. The reasons for that are fairly obvious from your question. Data that is not normalized can't be queried on, compared, etc. Either use the right column type, or don't query by the date. That's your choices.

Comment: *Not possible* can't be true for such an indispensable improvement. At the very least DateTime fields could be *added* instead of replacing the existing ones (and sync them with triggers). I'd certainly try to twist s/o's arm.

Answer (score 0):

If There's **absolutely** no way to change the database design, as suggested in the comments, You could try either to get all the data and convert to `date` locally or create a view in the DB where the value will be converted to `date` type.

For the first option you could do something like this:

```
.Select(f=> new {Record=f, Date=DateTime.Parse(f.Date)})
.Where(f => f.Date >= Date1  && f.Date <= Date2)
```

I think you can convert it in sql directly with `SqlFunctions` (though, i've never tried it)

```
.Select(f=> new {Record=f, Date= SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 0, f.Date)})
.Where(f => f.Date >= Date1  && f.Date <= Date2)
```

Or directly in the where:

```
.Where(f => SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 0, f.Date) >= Date1  && SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 0, f.Date) <= Date2)
```

The second option is the create a `view` in the DB with `convert (datetime, *yourDateField*, 101)` -- *not sure about the `101` in your case.*

**Just to clarify:** None of these is optimized. The best would be to change the DB design